# Scipy Interpolate Gridded Data Won't Display With Mathplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, imagemagick

I am mostly a Python/Numpy/Scipy novice, but know image processing and Imagemagick well. My ultimate goal is to use Python/Numpy/Scipy to interpolate 2 sparse grids of data into images that can then be used as x and y displacement maps in Imagemagick to warp one into into another. I am somewhat following https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html.

I have one image (src):

[image]

that I eventually want to warp into (dst), though that image and the warping process are not relevant to the problem presented here (other than the grid intersection values):

[image]

I have two sets of x,y control points, one from each image as shown in http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/grid16_control_points2.txt

I have computed zx=xsrc-xdst+127.5 and zy=ysrc-ydst+127.5 as the values at dstx,dsty coordinates and I want to interpolate those values over the full 129x129 image. (Note that the additional 127.5 is for Imagemagick use -- any value in the displacement map image above that will move in one direction and values below will move in the opposite direction)

**My code below does not show any error messages and no images are displayed. I think I have most working, except for the plt.show. But, I hope someone can point out what I am doing wrong.**

```
#!/bin/python3.7

"""

Use interpolation on a grid of x,y,z values, where z is either xdiff or ydiff for use as imagemagick 2D displacement maps

"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata as griddata
from PIL import Image

# test grid data is from https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#polynomial (zx and zy are xsrc-xdst and ysrc-ydst)

# python lists of x,y dst control points and zx=xsrc-xdiff, zy=ysrc-ydiff offsets to be interpolated over full image of size 129x129
xy = [[8.5,7.5], [20.5,5.5], [33.5,3.5], [48.5,1.5], [64.5,1.5], [80.5,1.5], [95.5,3.5], [109.5,5.5], [121.5,7.5], [5.5,20.5], [17.5,16.5], [31.5,14.5], [46.5,12.5], [64.5,11.5], [81.5,12.5], [97.5,15.5], [111.5,16.5], [123.5,19.5], [2.5,33.5], [14.5,31.5], [29.5,28.5], [45.5,26.5], [64.5,24.5], [83.5,26.5], [99.5,28.5], [113.5,31.5], [125.5,33.5], [1.5,48.5], [12.5,47.5], [26.5,45.5], [43.5,42.5], [64.5,40.5], [85.5,42.5], [103.5,45.5], [116.5,46.5], [127.5,48.5], [0.5,64.5], [11.5,64.5], [24.5,64.5], [41.5,64.5], [64.5,64.5], [87.5,64.5], [103.5,64.5], [117.5,64.5], [128.5,64.5], [1.5,80.5], [12.5,81.5], [25.5,83.5], [42.5,86.5], [64.5,87.5], [86.5,86.5], [103.5,83.5], [116.5,81.5], [127.5,80.5], [2.5,95.5], [14.5,97.5], [28.5,100.5], [45.5,103.5], [64.5,104.5], [83.5,102.5], [100.5,100.5], [114.5,97.5], [125.5,95.5], [5.5,109.5], [17.5,111.5], [30.5,114.5], [46.5,116.5], [64.5,117.5], [81.5,116.5], [97.5,114.5], [111.5,111.5], [123.5,109.5], [8.5,121.5], [19.5,123.5], [33.5,125.5], [48.5,127.5], [64.5,127.5], [80.5,127.5], [95.5,125.5], [109.5,123.5], [121.5,120.5]]
zx = [119.5, 123.5, 126.5, 127.5, 127.5, 127.5, 128.5, 130.5, 134.5, 122.5, 126.5, 128.5, 129.5, 127.5, 126.5, 126.5, 128.5, 132.5, 125.5, 129.5, 130.5, 130.5, 127.5, 124.5, 124.5, 126.5, 130.5, 126.5, 131.5, 133.5, 132.5, 127.5, 122.5, 120.5, 123.5, 128.5, 127.5, 132.5, 135.5, 134.5, 127.5, 120.5, 120.5, 122.5, 127.5, 126.5, 131.5, 134.5, 133.5, 127.5, 121.5, 120.5, 123.5, 128.5, 125.5, 129.5, 131.5, 130.5, 127.5, 124.5, 123.5, 125.5, 130.5, 122.5, 126.5, 129.5, 129.5, 127.5, 126.5, 126.5, 128.5, 132.5, 119.5, 124.5, 126.5, 127.5, 127.5, 127.5, 128.5, 130.5, 134.5]
zy = [120.5, 122.5, 124.5, 126.5, 126.5, 126.5, 124.5, 122.5, 120.5, 123.5, 127.5, 129.5, 131.5, 132.5, 131.5, 128.5, 127.5, 124.5, 126.5, 128.5, 131.5, 133.5, 135.5, 133.5, 131.5, 128.5, 126.5, 127.5, 128.5, 130.5, 133.5, 135.5, 133.5, 130.5, 129.5, 127.5, 127.5, 127.5, 127.5, 127.5, 127.5, 127.5, 127.5, 127.5, 127.5, 127.5, 126.5, 124.5, 121.5, 120.5, 121.5, 124.5, 126.5, 127.5, 128.5, 126.5, 123.5, 120.5, 119.5, 121.5, 123.5, 126.5, 128.5, 130.5, 128.5, 125.5, 123.5, 122.5, 123.5, 125.5, 128.5, 130.5, 134.5, 132.5, 130.5, 128.5, 128.5, 128.5, 130.5, 132.5, 135.5]

# convert python lists to numpy arrays
axy = np.asarray(xy, dtype=float)
azx = np.asarray(zx, dtype=float)
azy = np.asarray(zy, dtype=float)

# define integer grid onto which to interpolate
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:129, 0:129]

# do interpolations
xdisplace = griddata(axy, azx, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
ydisplace = griddata(axy, azy, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')

# replace all NAN with zero
xxdisplace = np.nan_to_num(xdisplace, copy=True)
yydisplace = np.nan_to_num(ydisplace, copy=True)

# Note: 3rd order polynomial interpolation can go wild and produce NAN values outside the normal range
# replace all NAN with zero
xxdisplace = np.nan_to_num(xdisplace, copy=True)
yydisplace = np.nan_to_num(ydisplace, copy=True)

# replace zero with 127.5
xxdisplace[xxdisplace == 0] = 127.5
yydisplace[yydisplace == 0] = 127.5

# display a subsection to examine interpolation
xxdsub = xxdisplace[0:5, 0:5]
print(xxdsub)

# display another subsection to examine interpolation
xxdsub = xxdisplace[60:65, 60:65]
print(xxdsub)

# save images
xdimg = Image.fromarray(xxdisplace.astype('uint8'))
ydimg = Image.fromarray(yydisplace.astype('uint8'))
xdimg.save('xdimg.png')
ydimg.save('ydimg.png')

# display images
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(xxdisplace.astype('uint8'))
plt.imshow(yydisplace.astype('uint8'))
plt.show()
```

I have modified my original code to add code to replace NAN with zero and then zeros with 127.5. But I get no error messages and no images displayed. (In other scripts plt.imshow() works fine).

The first xdsub now contains only values of 127.5 (from NAN)

```
[[127.5 127.5 127.5 127.5 127.5]
 [127.5 127.5 127.5 127.5 127.5]
 [127.5 127.5 127.5 127.5 127.5]
 [127.5 127.5 127.5 127.5 127.5]
 [127.5 127.5 127.5 127.5 127.5]]
```

The second xdsub data shows reasonably interpolated data.

[[129.12950391 129.13466567 129.14438372 129.15604101 129.16453265]
 [128.77872804 128.78027629 128.78368175 128.79182482 128.7988161 ]
 [128.41763609 128.42225153 128.4226885  128.42491114 128.43014312]
 [128.0492988  128.05418802 128.05800038 128.05793775 128.05925686]
 [127.68687259 127.68699624 127.68719118 127.68750429 127.68722127]]

**Any suggestions about my code will be most welcome.**

I am using Python 3.7.2, Numpy 1.16.1, Scipy 1.2.1 and Matplotlib 3.0.2 (all installed via MacPorts on my Mac OSX Sierra)

Comment: I replaced the plt.imshow(xxdisplace.astype('uint8')) with PIL xdimg.show() and it works. It also works with Skimage io.imshow(). But I would still like to understand how to make it display with plt.imshow. **It seems to launch matplotlib.pyplot, but then immediately closes it as if the data were not compatible.** Reading and image with OpenCV cv2 and then displaying with Mathplotlib.pyplot works fine.

Answer (score 0):

By default `griddata()`'s parameter *fill_value* is set to *nan*.
Reason for large negative numbers is the results of converting *nan* to *int*. You can try by removing `.astype(int)`.

Comment: `@bollence`. Thanks for the answer. I originally did not have `.astype(int)` and got NAN for all values in the subsection. So just removing that will not help. The problem is that it is not interpolating my data. Assuming its fill value is indeed NAN, then why is it not overrigiding those values with my interpolated data. I will remove it in my post if that will help other.

Comment: I have removed the .astype(int) and added new content. The NAN gave me a clue to look at other parts of the image, which were fine. The NAN came from the perimeter where the 3rd order polynomial did not fit well. I fixed some other issues. Now, the only issue is that I get no displayed images from plt.imshow, but I can get it to work with PIL's x.show()

Comment: @fmw42  `plt.imshow(xxdisplace,cmap='gray', vmin = 0, vmax = 255)`