# Distortion correction with open CV

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, calibration, distortion

I am trying to correct image distortion with open CV.
The theory for the distortion I am trying to correct is a combined barrel and pincushion distortion like this:

[image: Combined barrel and pincushion distortion]

I am not working with a normal camera here, but with a galvanometer scanning system (like this: http://www.chinagalvo.com/Content/uploads/2019361893/201912161511117936592.gif), so I cannot just record a checkerboard pattern like all the OpenCV guides suggest.

But I can move the scanner to a target position and measure the actual position of the laser beam in the image plane, which plots e.g. to this:

[image: Actual image overlayed with target image]

So I put those values into OpenCV's `calibrateCamera` function in this script:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

targetPosX = np.array([-4., -2., 0., 2., 4., -4., -2., 0., 2., 4., -4., -2., 2., 4., -4., -2., 0., 2., 4., -4., -2., 0., 2., 4.])
targetPosY = np.array([-4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.])
actualPosX = np.array([-4.21765834, -2.14708042, -0.07755157, 1.9910175, 4.05941744, -4.17816164, -2.10614537, -0.03775821, 2.02883123, 4.09875409, -4.13937186, -2.07079973, 2.07072068, 4.1377518, -4.10200901, -2.03229052, 0.0367603, 2.10655379, 4.17627114, -4.06449305, -1.99426964, 0.07737988, 2.14365487, 4.21625359])
actualPosY = np.array([-4.04808315, -4.08681247, -4.12545265, -4.16807799, -4.20657896, -1.98568911, -2.0217478, -2.06356789, -2.10326313, -2.14456442, 0.07567631, 0.03889721, -0.04043382, -0.08069954, 2.14054726, 2.09940048, 2.05965315, 2.02167639, 1.9800822, 4.20167787, 4.16215278, 4.12334605, 4.08099448, 4.04376011])

scale = 100 # px / mm
height = 9 * scale # range of measured points is -4 to 4mm --> show area from -4.5 to 4.5 with 100 px / mm
width = 9 * scale

def scale_and_shift(array, scl, shift):
    array *= scl
    array += shift
    return array

# shift recorded positon into image coordinate system
targetPosX = scale_and_shift(targetPosX, scale, width / 2.)
targetPosY = scale_and_shift(targetPosY, scale, height / 2.)
actualPosX = scale_and_shift(actualPosX, scale, width / 2.)
actualPosY = scale_and_shift(actualPosY, scale, height / 2.)

# create images
target_image = np.full((height,width), 255)
combined_image = np.full((height,width), 255)
actual_image = np.full((height,width), 255) 
for i in range(len(targetPosX)):
    cv2.circle(target_image, (int(targetPosX[i]), int(targetPosY[i])), 20, 0, -1)
    
    # circle in combined image is target position, full point is actual position
    cv2.circle(combined_image, (int(targetPosX[i]), int(targetPosY[i])), 20, 0, 5)
    cv2.circle(combined_image, (int(actualPosX[i]), int(actualPosY[i])), 20, 0, -1)

    cv2.circle(actual_image, (int(actualPosX[i]), int(actualPosY[i])), 20, 0, -1)

cv2.imwrite("combined_before.png", combined_image)

# create point lists for calibrateCamera function. set 3rd dimension to zero.
targetPoints = np.array([np.vstack([targetPosX, targetPosY]).T]).astype("float32")
targetPoints_zero = np.array([np.vstack([targetPosX, targetPosY, list(np.zeros(len(targetPosX)))]).T]).astype("float32")
imagePoints = np.array([np.vstack([actualPosX, actualPosY]).T]).astype("float32")
imagePoints_zero = np.array([np.vstack([actualPosX, actualPosY, np.zeros(len(actualPosX))]).T]).astype("float32")

# read image to apply to
# saving and reading because just passing the actual_image somehow didn't work
cv2.imwrite("image.png", actual_image)
img = cv2.imread("image.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# calulate distortion matrix
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(targetPoints_zero, imagePoints, (h,w), None, None)

# refine distortion matrix to avoid cut-off
newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w,h), 1, (w,h))

# undistort
dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)

cv2.imwrite('calibresult.png', dst)
cv2.imwrite("correction.png", dst - actual_image)

for i in range(len(targetPosX)):
    # circle in combined image is target position, full point is actual position
    cv2.circle(dst, (int(targetPosX[i]), int(targetPosY[i])), 20, 0, 5)

cv2.imwrite('combined_result.png', dst)
```

However, the result is not as expected - the corrected image does not line up with the target image (full dots - corrected actual points. Circles - target points):
[image: Corrected actual image (full dots) overlayed with the target image (circles)]

Comparing before and after shows that just a minimal correction / distortion compensation was applied (just calculated the diff of before and after for the actual image:

[image: Difference of before an after correction for the actual image]

Is there any way I can tweak the `calibrateCamera`? Or is this just the wrong tool for this job?

Comment: Use more calibration images/samples. Does your galvanometer even distort with a camera model? You could try to limit the number of distortion coefficients and fix the principal point to the center, if this makes sense in your setting and check if it gives better results.

Comment: You could use Scipy.interpolate.griddata. See my example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408596/scipy-interpolate-gridded-data-wont-display-with-mathplotlib-pyplot

Comment: Given the gridded x and y images as in the link in my previous comment, you can then use OpenCV cv2.remap() to warp the image to do the correction.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I have to post an answer.

For users that struggle with camera calibration might be helpful to keep in mind, that it is not always possible to fit perfectly a lens distortion model. And that if you are not sure about your lens, you can try both rectilinear, and fish-eye distortion. [link](https://euratom-software.github.io/calcam/html/intro_theory.html)

Before deep diving into the OpenCV calibration tweaking, you should read calibration [good practices](https://calib.io/blogs/knowledge-base/calibration-best-practices).

If your setup is precise enough, you might consider using **higher feature count**. Using fine patterns is preferable.

Try to simulate what people do with their chessboards. **Collect images from different areas and tilts**:

1. Try shifting the whole grid to different directions. Try to get as close to edges as possible. (there is the strongest distortion)
2. If you have an option to tilt your marking field, please do. Then you can calculate the "undistorted" points with basic geometry. (See [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates))

And finally, you can try to simulate different [calibration patterns](https://calib.io/blogs/knowledge-base/calibration-patterns-explained). For example asymmetric circles. If your setup is precise enough, you might be able to sample border of each circle.