# Getting rid of rainbows after griddata

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to use griddata to interpolate a picture after tomography and I'm getting weird rainbows on the edges of the warped picture that I'm trying to get rid of

[image: picture after homography]

```
@staticmethod
def warp(
        backward_projective_homography: np.ndarray,
        src_image: np.ndarray,
        dst_image_shape: tuple = (1088, 1452, 3)) -> np.ndarray:

    # return backward_warp
    x_src, y_src = np.arange(0, src_image.shape[1]), np.arange(0, src_image.shape[0])
    coord_mat_src = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(x_src, y_src)).reshape(-1, 2).transpose()
    ones_src = np.ones(coord_mat_src.shape[1]).astype(int)
    coord_mat_ones_src = np.vstack([coord_mat_src,ones_src])

    back_homo_dst = np.dot(backward_projective_homography, coord_mat_ones_src)
    z_row = back_homo_dst[-1,:]
    dst_coord_normalized = (back_homo_dst/np.array([z_row,]*3)).astype(int)

    dst_image = (np.zeros(dst_image_shape).astype(np.ubyte))
    x_dest_coord = np.clip(dst_coord_normalized[0,:], 0, (dst_image_shape[1]-1))
    y_dest_coord = np.clip(dst_coord_normalized[1,:], 0, (dst_image_shape[0]-1))
    dst_image[y_dest_coord, x_dest_coord, :] = src_image[coord_mat_src[1, :], coord_mat_src[0, :], :]

    points = (np.vstack([y_dest_coord, x_dest_coord])).astype(int).transpose()
    values = dst_image[y_dest_coord, x_dest_coord, :].astype(np.uint8)

    grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[min(y_dest_coord):max(y_dest_coord), min(x_dest_coord):max(x_dest_coord)]
    grid_image = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic').astype(np.uint8)  # Correct
    return grid_image
```

Comment: Check the values in your image. Are you getting "NAN" in those regions? If so, change all NAN to zero, for example. That is what I did with the example that I did. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408596/scipy-interpolate-gridded-data-wont-display-with-mathplotlib-pyplot

Comment: Can you please post an executable code sample (code that we can copy, paste and execute)? For making it simpler to answer, consider adding the input image to your post.